# Is this code a working critical section wrapper class

Tags: c++, windows, api, critical-section

I've actually got 2 questions, heres the first one.

Using the code I found at two different sites, I wrote those two critical section wrapper classes.

Is it going to work?

```
#ifndef CRITICALSECTION_H
#define CRITICALSECTION_H
#include "windows.h"



class CriticalSection{
    long m_nLockCount;
    long m_nThreadId;
    typedef CRITICAL_SECTION cs;
    cs m_tCS;
public:
    CriticalSection(){
        ::InitializeCriticalSection(&m_tCS);
        m_nLockCount = 0;
        m_nThreadId = 0;
    }
    ~CriticalSection(){ ::DeleteCriticalSection(&m_tCS); }
    void Enter(){ ::EnterCriticalSection(&m_tCS);  }
    void Leave(){  ::LeaveCriticalSection(&m_tCS); }
    void Try();
};


class LockSection{
    CriticalSection* m_pCS;
public:
    LockSection(CriticalSection* pCS){
        m_pCS = pCS;
        if(m_pCS)m_pCS->Enter();
    }
    ~LockSection(){
        if(m_pCS)m_pCS->Leave();
    }
}

/*

Safe class basic structure;

class SafeObj
{
     CriticalSection m_cs;

public:
    void SafeMethod()
    {
        LockSection myLock(&m_cs);
        //add code to implement the method ...

    }
};



*/
#endif
```

And the second question. While browsing **[here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/xylock.aspx)**, I noticed that the author did not include

**::Initialize , Delete , Enter , Leave** critical sections . Aren't these needed for the class to work properly? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Those functions are in the `XYCriticalSection` class.  In your code, the `SafeMethod` should be `LockSection myLock(&m_cs);`

Comment: If your'e asking for a critique of your code, post it here:http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Appears OK.  The Initialize, Delete, Enter and Leave functions are there in your small posted example.  Not sure what you think is missing?

Comment: I would make `CriticalSection::Enter/Leave/Try` protected, and `friend LockSection`, which minimizes errors.  Also, `CriticalSection` should have a private undefined assignment operator, and `LockSection` should have copy/assignment operators.  Then you're totally safe.

Comment: Thanks guys for answering so fast! Though the second question remains, why didn't the author of the codeproject article I mentioned above, didn't use ::Initialize , ::Enver , ::Leave etc ?

Comment: Please don't make us go elsewhere to read some other article. Post code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LockSection` class uses [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) to call `Enter` and `Leave`. When the object is created, the `Enter` is called. When the object is destroyed (by going out of scope) the `Leave` is called.

`Initialize` and `Delete` are called by the `CriticalSection` class' constructor and destructor.

Learn RAII, learn it well. It is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer the first question. The second question involves code at a different site and you should only ask one question at a time. Perhaps someone else will answer the second question.

The code you included will work correctly. The members `m_nLockCount` and `m_nThreadId` are unused and not needed. The `Try()` method has no implementation but you can just delete it

Personally I would raise an exception if `m_pCS` is not assigned. That's a clear error condition. Silently continuing and pretending that the resource is protected is an obvious danger.

Comment: I am planning to use them but first , I had to make sure that the code was alright =). Thanks for the note about the possible error when m_pCS isn't assigned !